# LINQ select not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a list on multiple properties and then output a list of a single property using LINQ.

I can get the desired (unfiltered) output using just the following line

```
var query = l.Select(x => x.prop4).ToList();
```

However, using this after several `Where` clauses is giving me list of TestObject's intead of a list of prop4's

Please can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestObject> l = new List<TestObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            l.Add(new TestObject() { prop1 = i, prop2 = i, prop3 = i, prop4 = i});
        }

        //var query = l.Select(x => x.prop4).ToList(); //Correct output type but unfiltered!!

        var query = l.Where(x => x.prop1 > 2);
        query = query.Where(x => x.prop2 > 4);
        query = query.Where(x => x.prop3 > 6);
        query.Select(x => x.prop4).ToList(); //Outputs List of TestObject and not List of prop4

    }
}

public class TestObject
{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
    public int prop3 { get; set; }
    public int prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I run the above code in LINQPad I get a List<Int> returned.

Comment: That's not possible. Please copy and paste your exact code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating your query vairable to hold reference to list of your property, so your result is lost somewhere in memory:

```
var result  = query.Select(x => x.prop4).ToList();

// now use result to do what needed
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the value of query.Select to anything:
Try this :

```
var t = query.Select(x => x.prop4).ToList(); //Outputs List of TestObject and not List of prop4
        t.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output : 
7
8
9